# AngularJS dynamic metatags - Is it possible to reevaluate a dynamic meta tag? Specifically apple-itunes-app smart banner meta tag

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, angularjs, meta

In AngularJS, I am trying to have a dynamic apple-itunes-app smart banner for iOS safari. I have one single  section for the app in my index.html as I am using ui-router.I have successfully displayed the smart banner using this metatag:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=111111111">
```

Now I am trying to add the app-argument dynamically depending on which AngularJS controller is active. I wish to allow users to access the same content in the app, like this:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=111111111, app-argument={{inAppPath}}">
```

When I check in my dev tools as I go through my different views loading all the controllers the variable( `{{inAppPath}}` ), updates correctly. I know the inAppPath works when entered directly on the address bar. Still the banner will only open the app in the home page, not following in app-argument. Initially, I believe the app-argument is not getting set in time for the browser to evaluate it. Is there a way to reevaluate or reload the meta-tag/smart banner when the app-argument changes?

I've tried:

- Removing old tag and appending new tag from the head with jqlite.
- Using navigator.platform to detect iOS, but cant figure out how to
  see if app is installed.